# How to maximize quadratic form with a integer variables or its relaxation

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, non-convex-optimization, relaxations

Let $A$ be a positive semidefinite matrix. Also, let $\forall i\in [1,n], x_i \in \{-1,1\}$. And finally, for some of indices $I\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$, values of $x_i\in \{-1,1\}$ are known. Therefore, the problem is to solve for remaining values of $x_i, i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}-I$. Let $x=[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$.How to solve the optimization problem $max_x x^\mathsf{T}Ax$ given this constraints?

If one relaxes variables from $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$  to $x_i \in [-1,1]$, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your second sentence indicates that all $x_i=\pm 1$ for *all* $i$. Your third sentence says that *some* $x_i$ are either 1 or -1. That is a bit confusing.

Comment: @prubin, Thank you. I corrected the question. Do you have any suggestions for which way to go?

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing useful to suggest. I know there are solvers that will handle nonconvex integer problems (though not necessarily with a guarantee of optimality in all cases), but I have no personal familiarity with them. Hopefully someone who does will answer.